# Issue integrating analytics plugin in Mobile First Application project

Tags: google-analytics, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I have a problem...
I'm try to add this plugin: https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.
I'm develop an application with: AngularJS, Ionic and Mobile First Platform 7.1(MFP), in this version of MFP I must add the plugin manually.
iOS works fine.
My problem is Android:
**Error: "The import com.google.android cannot be resolved".**
I download Google Play Services with SDK but the problem continues... 
Any idea to solve this problem?
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This other plugin https://github.com/appfeel/analytics-google uses gradle dependencies which should solve this problem.

Other option could be to remove google play dependency from the plugin you mentioned and manually modify gradle (actually I don't recommend this option as gradle gets generated automatically each time you remove/add the platform).

Other option is to modify the plugin itself (maybe a github fork). Here you can see what should it be modified: https://github.com/appfeel/analytics-google/pull/11/files

Comment: Hi, I continue using the same plugin that I was using. The problem is solved using gradle to manage dependencies. Thanks!